# Connect Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized: The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure

Tags: neo4j

I typed bolt://localhost:7687 as a connect URL, 
        neo4j as user and
        neo4j as psw
but I faced this error msg

> " Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized: The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure."

what should I do please

Comment: How are you running Neo4j? Are you using Neo4j Desktop, or running via service/console?

Comment: I used it as a Desktop

Comment: does this got a relation with wamp server or another program ?cause all I did is installing Neo4j and running it

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new database instance with Neo4j Desktop it will ask you there and then to change the default password of neo4j to something else, and it will not let you keep it as neo4j. This is most likely why you are getting that error.

If you are unable to remember what password you selected at the time of creation of the database, you can change it via Neo4j Desktop by navigating to the 'Manage' cog on that database, click the 'Administration' tab, and change the password there.

Comment: in my case I tried adding a new user and granted admin role, then using those credentials in my node browser connection. But it is still generating `Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized`